# Read access violation

Tags: c++, exception, access-violation

I'm trying to write Monopoly game and I'm stuck.

So let start by showing my class hierarchy

```
class Player {  
    std::vector<Property> m_properties;
public:
    void addProperty(const Property &p_property) { m_properties.push_back(p_property); }
    void showProperties();
    void showPlayer();
}

void Player::showProperties() {
    for (int i = 0; i < m_properties.size(); i++) {
        std::cout << "Property nr " << i << "\n" << m_properties[i].showProperty();
    }
}

void Player::showPlayer() {
    std::cout << "Name: " << m_name << "\n"
              << "Position: " << m_position << "\n"
              << "Cash: " << m_cash << "\n"
              << "In jail?: "; 
                if (m_inJail== true) std::cout << "Yes\n";
                else std::cout << "No\n";
    std::cout << "Properties: \n";
    showProperties();
}
```

Class Property and its showProperty() function

```
std::string Property::showProperty() const {
    std::string s = "Name: " + m_name + "\n"
        + "Group:" + m_group + "\n"
        + "Price:" + std::to_string(m_price) + "\n"
        + "Owner:" + m_pOwner->getName();
    return s; 
}
```

And here is method that adds Property to Player vector

```
void PropertyManager::buyProperty(Property &p_property, Player &p_player) { 
    if (p_property.getOwner() == nullptr) {
        if (p_player.getCash() >= p_property.getPrice()) {
            p_player.addProperty(p_property);
            p_player.takeCash(p_property.getPrice());
            p_property.setOwner(p_player);
        }
        else cout << "Sorry, you don't have enough cash. \n";
    }
    else cout << "Sorry, this property is owned by somebody else. \n";
}
```

So as you can see, Player contains vector, Property has method to return string with basic data about Property object. In PropertyManager class I have method buyProperty that checks if its available and then adds selected Property to selected Player, it works, player loses cash, propety gets owner. But now I want to show all properties that player has. Here comes my `Player::showPlayer()` that calls `Player::showProperties()` which on the other hand calls `Property::showProperty()` like that `m_properties[i].showProperty()`

Finnaly my main function

```
int main() {
    Field *board[10];
    Property testProperty(PropertyType::BuildingArea, 5, "Test", "Test", 3, 1000, 100, 400, 150);
    Player player("Testplayer", 5000);  
    PropertyManager manager;
    board[0] = &testProperty;   
    manager.buyProperty(testProperty, player);  
    player.showPlayer();    

    std::cin.get();
}
```

Unfortunatelly it throws exception

> Unhandled exception thrown: read access violation.
>   _Right_data was nullptr.

Seems like  `Player::showProperties()` is causing this, cus when I dont call this function, program works.

Comment: compile with debug options, run under debugger. It will tell you where its failing

Comment: I'm guessing your constructor for `Player` uses that second argument to initialize the vector of properties, and this is where the mistake is. Show the constructor.

Comment: Voting to close because: "Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [mcve] example."

Comment: `Player::Player(std::string p_name, double p_cash) : m_name(p_name), m_cash(p_cash), m_position(0), m_inJail(false), m_daysLeftInJail(0) { }` About error statement, I just installed newest VS 2017 and tbh I have no idea why it doesnt show error output, program just stops and throws exception, If I run without debugging I get same error as I posted

Comment: general advice, dont store objects in your vectors, store smart pointers to them (shared_ptr is probably what you want). Why? Because you now have a copy of the object in the vector. If you change the original object (change its price for example) then that is not reflected in the vector contents.

Comment: step through with the debugger then, you will see where it goes bang

Comment: I cant step through it, VS opens xstring file and stops on this line `const size_type _Right_size = _Right_data._Mysize;`... i really have no idea how to move on now

Comment: @pm100 That is generally bad advice - C++ is a value-based language; if possible, you should store values, not pointers.

Comment: This line causes crash `std::cout << "Property nr " << i << "\n" << m_properties[i].showProperty();` m_properties is vector<Property>, showProperty() is method from Property class

Comment: @Emdzej93 -- `m_pOwner->getName`  -- There is no indication, where, when, or how `m_pOwner` is initialized, gets its value, etc.  If I were to guess, your issue has to do with this pointer or other pointers that you have in your class(es) that you're not showing.

Comment: At first its initialized with nullptr in constructor initialization list, then its set in member function `void setOwner(Player& player) { m_pOwner = &player; }` Function is called in code snipped I posted above

Comment: @Emdzej93 -- Also, this looks *very* suspicious -- `p_property.setOwner(p_player);` -- Here you're using a reference to set the owner, but here `m_pOwner->getName` your getting the owner as if it's a pointer.   This is a bad design -- the `buyProperty` takes a reference to an owner, but then you're actually getting the pointer to the owner and storing it?

Comment: @Emdzej93 -- Well that is a bad design, being honest with you.  If that `player` goes out of scope, i.e. dies off in the caller's code, your `Property` object now has an invalid pointer value as one of the members.

Comment: Im confused right now, in class Property I haveprivate member `Player *m_pOwner;` initialized with nullptr, then can be set by public method `void setOwner(Player& player) { m_pOwner = &player; }` So if I understand it correct, I pass argument by reference (not making copy) and then assign its adress under m_pOwner pointer, right? Then in  `buyProperty(Property &p_property, Player &p_player)` I again pass argument as reference and call my function `p_property.setOwner(p_player);` Dont really get what is wrong here, but its like 10th hour in front of code today so...

Comment: @Emdzej93 -- Well, not posting a [mcve] dragged this question out.  If you had done that from way back at the start of the discussion, the problem may have been diagnosed and explained.